# Big array of size 1mega caused high CPU?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, cpu-usage

I have a multithreaded server application. This application receives data from sockets then handles these data like unpacking package, adding to data queue, etc, the function is as below. This function is called frequently. There is a select statement and if it finds there is data it will call this function to receive):

```
         //the main function used to receive 
         //file data from clients
         void service(void){
              while(1){
                   ....
                   struct timeval timeout;
                   timeout.tv_sec = 3;

                   ...
                   ret = select(maxFd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
                   if (ret > 0){
                       //get socket from SocketsMap
                       //if fd in SocketsMap and its being set
                       //then receive data from the socket
                       receive_data(fd);
                   }
              }
         } 

         void receive_data(int fd){
              const int ONE_MEGA = 1024 * 1024;

              //char *buffer = new char[ONE_MEGA]; consumes much less CPU
              char buffer[ONE_MEGA]; // cause high CPU 
              int readn = recv(fd, buffer, ONE_MEGA, 0);

              //handle the data
         }
```

I found the above consumes too much CPU -- usually 80% to 90%, but if I create the buffer from heap instead the CPU is only 14%. Why?

**[update]**
Added more code

**[update2]**
The stangest thing is that I also wrote another simple data-receiving server and client. The server simply receives data from sockets then discard it. Both types of space allocating works almost the same, no big difference in CPU usage. In the multithreaded server application which has the problem, I even reset the process stack size to 30M, using array still results in the problem, but allocating from heap solves it. I don't know why.

Regarding the "sizeof(buffer)", thanks for pointing out this, but I am 100% sure that it is not the problem, because in my application I don't use sizeof(buffer), but ONE_MEGA (1024*1024) instead.

By the way, there is one more thing to mention though I am not sure it's useful or not. **Replacing the array with a smaller one such as "char buffer[1024]; also decreases the cpu usage dramatically.**

**[update3]**
All sockets are in non-blocking mode.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: hi Petersson, sorry I don't quite understand why you say so. This might be a fact that allocating big stack size of array frequently caused high cpu, but can you help explain?

Comment: What was your process doing when you strace'd it? Did `/bin/time` show consistently different pagefault counts for the two versions?

Comment: Using large amounts of stack should not make something use more CPU, in my experience. But let me make some experiments...

Comment: it's receiving data. I use top to see the CPU usage and found it usually consumes 80% cpu, but if I use "buffer = new char[one_mega]" instead, the same process doing a same operation consumes only 14%.

Comment: As with any performance issue, did you compile with optimizations turned on before comparing the two versions?

Comment: Also, are you freeing your buffer? Otherwise, it could be that your 14% is reflecting the swapping...

Comment: Do you alter your `recv` line for the dynamic allocation test?  If you don't, `sizeof(buffer)` passed to `recv` will say that you want to read `sizeof(char*)` (probably 4 or 8 bytes) rather than 1Mb

Comment: @syam, both use the O3 optimization level

Comment: Well, of course "allocation" on stack is much faster than allocation on heap, but why do you allocate each time you receive, why not allocate one buffer and keep it forever?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I don't believe allocating once or many times will make that much of a difference - once you have chunked up the heap, it will probably give you the same lump of memory each time anyway [assuming there aren't too many other allocations going on, of course]. And it should give HIGHER cpu usage if the heap allocation is slow.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks for the suggestion, I should have used it this way. I  WILL!

Comment: My guess would be that select() is returning even when there isn't yet any data to read, and then your non-blocking recv() call returns EWOULDBLOCK, and then you go back to select() again, which wakes up immediately again, and so on -- hence busy-looping and eating up CPU.  It might be good to double check that you are calling FD_ZERO and FD_SET correctly, and to test FD_ISSET before calling receive_data(), and also to print out the value returned by recv() to see if it is actually giving you data when it is called, or not.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

const int M = 1024*1024;

void bigstack()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    unsigned long long time;
    char buffer[M];

    time = rdtsc();
    fread(buffer, M, 1, f);
    time = rdtsc() - time;
    fclose(f);
    cout << "bs: Time = " << time / 1000 << endl;
}


void bigheap()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    unsigned long long time;
    char *buffer = new char[M];

    time = rdtsc();
    fread(buffer, M, 1, f);
    time = rdtsc() - time;
    delete [] buffer;
    fclose(f);
    cout << "bh: Time = " << time / 1000 << endl;
}



int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    bigstack();
    bigheap();
    }
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
bs: Time = 8434
bh: Time = 7242
bs: Time = 1094
bh: Time = 2060
bs: Time = 842
bh: Time = 830
bs: Time = 785
bh: Time = 781
bs: Time = 782
bh: Time = 804
bs: Time = 782
bh: Time = 778
bs: Time = 792
bh: Time = 809
bs: Time = 785
bh: Time = 786
bs: Time = 782
bh: Time = 829
bs: Time = 786
bh: Time = 781
```

In other words, allocating from the stack of the heap makes absolutely no difference. The small amount of "slowness" in the beginning has to do with "warming up the caches".

And I'm fairly convinced that the reason your code behaves differently between the two is something else - maybe what simonc says: `sizeof buffer` is the problem?

Comment: wow, you wrote a test app so quickly, awesome! Resetting the array to size of 1024bytes also decrease the CPU usage dramatically! Is this information useful？

Comment: I think the longest time was to generate 1MB file to actually read... ;) - I can't explain why using a smaller buffer makes that much of a difference. Can you confirm that you are usign the `ONE_MEGA` as size when you are using `new` for the buffer?

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure, I spent the whole afternoon playing with the code snippet. I can't explain why array would cause the app to consume more cpu. The first thing I think of is the stack size, I doubt the stack is not enough so I reset the stack size to 30M using setrlimit(), but result is the same.

Comment: Well, I can't see any reason why `recv` should be much different from `fread` in it's handling of memory - it may take a bit longer or shorter to actually copy any received data, but other than that, I don't see why my benchmark wouldn't match, near enough, what your system is doing. Assuming your system is an x86 system, you could run my code (you'll have to generate your own `test.txt` file with about 1M of data in it).

Comment: it's a server application for forwarding files from clientA to ClientB, ClientC,... Firstly it reads file data from clientA socket, then wrote them into local file and finally fowards to other clients. Now I found the reading sockets operation (read data out from sockets and discard them) consumes too much CPU usage..

Comment: Maybe blind shot but try to check if crossing buffer size border of 4k size makes a difference.

Comment: For a 1MB buffer, there will be 255 to 257 "page boundary crossings", and typically, the buffer allocated by `new` isn't page-aligned either.

Comment: yes, i know but he wrote " Replacing the array with a smaller one such as "char buffer[1024]; also decreases the cpu usage dramatically" so i think he could find size when CPU usage goes high. It might by some clue or not, but you wont know if he wont check this.

Comment: Well, I have no idea. I'm just saying that 255 or 257 page-crossings should make very little difference, if any.

Comment: @BeginEnd I can go check this size border tomorrow.

Comment: Petersson, I really appreciate your help on this question, I see you left some comments to my other post. I will accept your comments to the other post of mine as the answer of this post, if you don't mind updating your comments to this post. Thanks again, petersson.

Comment: Just accept this answer, and upvote the other? Saves the same content being in two different answers.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that `recv` over a network and `fread` from a local file will have similar behavior.  `fread` has an additional layer of buffering, in addition to the possibility of partial read with `recv` on stream sockets.

Comment: @BenVoigt: And that will affect how much CPU it uses, based on where the allocation comes from? Of course the calls are behaving differently in some aspects. But not in the way that the memory is used. Although the data is cached, the "Oh, I've read this before" is not cached - each read will still fill the user-mode buffer in the same way. How the data got to the system shouldn't make a difference [remember, the OP is using `recv` after the system has said "you've got some data to deal with"]. Please tell me where I'm going wrong in my thinking here?

Answer (score 0):

If all things are equal, memory is memory and it shouldn't matter whether your buffer is on the heap or on the stack.

But clearly all things aren't equal. I suspect the allocation of the 1M buffer on the stack INTERFERES/OVERLAPS with the stack space allocated to the OTHER threads. That is, to grow the stack requires either relocating the stack of the current thread, or relocating the stacks of the other threads. This takes time. This time is not needed when allocating from the heap or if the stack allocation is small enough not to interfere, as it is with the 1K example.

Assuming you are using a Posix-compatible thread implementation, take a look at

```
pthread_create
pthread_attr_getstack
pthread_attr_setstack
```

for giving the thread with the 1M buffer more stack space at thread creation time.

-Jeff

Comment: I also suspect this point and reset the process stack size to 30M, only to find it doesn't work. The application has more than 60 threads running in it.

Answer (score -1):

You're ignoring the return value from `recv`.  That's not good.  Partial reads are a fact of life, and very likely if you pass such a large buffer.  When you start processing parts of the buffer that don't contain valid data, unexpected things could happen.

The maximum frame size for the most commonly used protocol is 64kB.  It's even possible (although unlikely) that something in the system only uses the lowest 16 bits of the buffer size, which incidentally you've set to zero.  Which that would cause `recv` to return immediately without doing anything, resulting in an endless loop and high CPU usage.

Of course none of this should be any different with a dynamically-allocated buffer, but if you *also* used `sizeof (buffer)` and ended up with the heap-user code reading only a pointer-sized chunk at once, it could be different.